# Slice indices must have an __index__ method

Tags: python, pandas

I work on a project where I have to use Pandas package, I got this error when I run it:

```
TypeError: slice indices must be integers or None or have an __index__ method
```

so my program looks like the following:

```
v_features = df.ix[:,1:29].columns

for i, cn in enumerate(df[v_features]):
    sns.distplot(df[cn][df.Class == 1], bins=50)
    sns.distplot(df[cn][df.Class == 0], bins=50)
```

Features contain the following:

```
 Index(['V1', 'V2', 'V3', 'V4', 'V5', 'V6', 'V7', 'V8', 'V9', 'V10', 'V11',
   'V12', 'V13', 'V14', 'V15', 'V16', 'V17', 'V18', 'V19', 'V20', 'V21',
   'V22', 'V23', 'V24', 'V25', 'V26', 'V27', 'V28'],
  dtype='object')
```

I don't know where I mess up my code

Comment: Please read your own subject and compare that with the error message. Those two are totally different!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have same issue and solution is from [this](https://github.com/mwaskom/seaborn/issues/1103#issuecomment-294212212):

> conda install -c conda-forge statsmodels

And then use:

```
a = df.loc[df.Class == 1, df.columns[1:29]]
b = df.loc[df.Class == 0, df.columns[1:29]]

for x in range(28):
    sns.distplot(a.iloc[:, x], bins=50)
    sns.distplot(b.iloc[:, x], bins=50)
```

Sample:

```
np.random.seed(234)
cols = ['V1', 'V2', 'V3', 'V4', 'V5', 'V6', 'V7', 'V8', 'V9', 'V10', 'V11',
   'V12', 'V13', 'V14', 'V15', 'V16', 'V17', 'V18', 'V19', 'V20', 'V21',
   'V22', 'V23', 'V24', 'V25', 'V26', 'V27', 'V28']
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(10, size=(10, 28)), columns=cols)
df['Class'] = df['V1'].gt(4).astype(int)

#print (df)

a = df.loc[df.Class == 1, df.columns[1:29]]
b = df.loc[df.Class == 1, df.columns[1:29]]


for x in range(28):
    sns.distplot(a.iloc[:, x], bins=50)
    sns.distplot(b.iloc[:, x], bins=50)
```

Comment: this is exactly What I look for, it works fine now, however I've just done : `conda install -c conda-forge statsmodels` without change My code, Thanks

Comment: Super, glad can help!

Comment: I think that I will remove this question because it has -1 in rating

Comment: It is up to you... But not sure if it is possible. But if need help with rep, (+3)

Comment: it's ok, i will save it